# ASP.Net Server prints data from DB but won't write to DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an issue with the connectionstring or something similiar I assume. since data is printed from DB but won't write to DB using the INSERT Query string.

here's the .cs code part:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Load_Data();
}

protected void Load_Data()
{
    DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();

    // connect to sql
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString);

    // create sql
    string sql = "SELECT Username, Fullname, Email FROM Users;";

    // command
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    // load data to dt
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dtUsers.Load(reader);

    con.Close();

    // print data to gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = dtUsers;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // connect to sql
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString);

    // create query
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Users (UserName,Passowrd,Email,FullName) VALUES ('" + txtUsername.Text + "','"+ txtPwd.Text + "','"+ txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtFullName.Text + "');";

    // command
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    // save data to db
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "won't write"? Do you get an error?

Comment: Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and at best might produce some nasty errors with unclean input and at worse you could lose your whole database or entire machine.

Comment: I am a beginner still studying.
anyway I meant the server won't stop loading once I hit the "Register" button.

Comment: I would also suggest using parameters to do inserts.

Comment: Which line of code is it stuck on?

Comment: Sadly, I do not know. How do I check that? @DavidG

Comment: Debug the code line by line and see where it stops.

Comment: I think you need to rebind your Datagridview, (After the con.Close() in Button1.Click event, put the `Load_Data` function, so that if the insert attempt is successful. It will refresh the datagridview with newly inserted data.